# How to fill the space outside of an image after rotating it

Tags: image-processing

I want to rotate this image  [image] by -50 degrees, and then fill up the black space around the rotated image [image]  with a bluish color. I can't find any documentation/answers that suggest how to do it. (Sorry about the poor question formatting).

Comment: `ImageRotate[]` takes a `Background` option. Set it to something like `ImageRotate[img, Background -> Blue]`.

Comment: You could also try `Padding -> "Fixed"` or `Padding -> "Reversed"` to repeat the pixel values of the image itself.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps this will motivate others or your own much better answer. In the following `imr` is the rotated image and `piece` is a piece of texture cropped from the image. It is then placed in an image of same dimension as `imr` and the in-painted then used to in-paint.

```
id = ImageDimensions[imr];
mask = Erosion[Binarize[MorphologicalComponents[imr] // Colorize], 5];
ol = Rasterize[Overlay[{Image[Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> id]], piece}
    ]];
ip = Inpaint[ol, Binarize[ol]];
Inpaint[ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[imr, mask], ImageSubtract[ip, mask]], 
 ColorNegate@mask, Method -> "FastMarching"]
```

Options:

```
Manipulate[
 Inpaint[ImageAdd[ImageMultiply[imr, mask], ImageSubtract[ip, mask]], 
  ColorNegate@mask, Method -> method], {method,
  {"TotalVariation", "FastMarching", "NavierStokes", 
   "TextureSynthesis"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! +1 :-)

Comment: Could be tidied up a lot more but do not have time at present

Comment: The `"TextureSynthesis"` setting looks to be the best for me.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I did this in a rush...could Abe done better. I too like texture synthesis and could crop out extraneous if desired...:)

Comment: This is a beautiful answer.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe thank you,,,but play around for yourself to get what you want :)

Answer (score 14):

As already commented you can use the [`Background`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Background.html) option for [`ImageRotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageRotate.html).
You might use [`DominantColors`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DominantColors.html) to select a background color.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr60D.png"];

ImageRotate[img, -50 °,
 Background -> DominantColors[img, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for introducing me to `DominantColors` +1 for that. :)